# Coordinates not stored in Array when inserted

Tags: arrays, swift, insert, coordinates

I'm trying to store coordinates in an array. The code runs fine, however after each iteration of new implemented coordinates, the array count still remains the same?

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01,0.01) //shows the size of map screen
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    let LAT = Double(location.coordinate.latitude)
    let LONG = Double(location.coordinate.longitude)
    var locationArray = [Double]()
    locationArray.insert(contentsOf: [LAT, LONG], at: 0)
    print(locationArray.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening, because you are creating a new locationArray in each iteration. You need to declare the **locationArray** outside of the scope of the update, where you are inserting your coordinates.

```
var locationArray = [Double]()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01,0.01) //shows the size of map screen
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    let LAT = Double(location.coordinate.latitude)
    let LONG = Double(location.coordinate.longitude)
    locationArray.insert(contentsOf: [LAT, LONG], at: 0)
    print(locationArray.count)
}
```